I accidentally sent ONDO tokens to its Contract Address
I mistakenly sent my ERC-20 token (ONDO) to ONDO Contract address. Transaction hash is 0xed0ade205a2380adaabb9d2185abcd0313f220b8b381a189bc5d62ba83d3fbf4. Please, I accidentally sent ONDO tokens to its Contract Address- 0xfAbA6f8e4a5E8Ab82F62fe7C39859FA577269BE3.
Please, can you help me check if ONDO contract owners has transfer functionality to enable them send me back the token. I will appreciate links or tools to run the checks too.
Thank you as you help me out.

There isn't any way to do that. I recommend joining their Telegram group here and asking for help there.
